# PHP script to automatically convert sitemap.xml to well formatted clickable sitemap.html?

Tags: php, html, xml, sitemap

I have the sitemap of my website in an XML file in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.mywebsite.com//index.html</loc>
    <lastmod>2014-08-16</lastmod>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
// ... etc.
```

How can I *automatically* create an HTML page from this XML file containing a well formatted nice-looking clickable sitemap for the visitors of my website? Ideally this should be a PHP script which outputs the desired HTML to the browser.

EDIT: I have created some code which you can look at in the accepted solution. How can this code be optimized?

Comment: You are probably thinking of the problem backwards.  An XML site map should likely be generated in a dynamic fashion on any site of sufficient complexity. It sounds like you need to determine a strategy for representing your site structure in code and use this to dynamically generate both your XML and HTML site maps.

Comment: @MikeBrant Please re-read my question. I wrote: "I HAVE ... an XML file", so I don't need to "generate it dynamically".

Comment: @putvande I tried to search a solution with Google. Since I did not find a solution, I tried here.

Comment: @user1580348 Judging by your reputation I can at least assume you have been using this forum for a while. You should know by now it's considered bad form to post a question without any code that you have tried in it and simply ask "How do I do X?" This forum is for specific programming problems. If you don't demonstrate a specific problem in your OP, which you didn't, the question should be closed. Which is what I recommended when reviewing this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since so far nobody provided a solution, I wrote my own solution:

```
<?php

$thisbasedir = '../mywebsite/';
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->load($thisbasedir . "sitemap.xml");
$data = $dom->getElementsByTagName('loc');

echo '<!DOCTYPE html>';
echo '<HTML>';
echo '<HEAD>';
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />';
echo '</HEAD>';
echo '<BODY>';
echo ("<table>");

foreach ($data as $node)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    $thisurl = $node->textContent;
    $thisbasename = basename($thisurl);
    $thistitle = get_title_tag_from_htmlpage($thisbasedir . $thisbasename);
    $thisdescription = get_description_from_htmlpage($thisbasedir . $thisbasename);
    echo ("<td>" .
          '<a href="' . $thisurl . '">' .
              $thistitle . ' (' . $thisdescription . ')' .
          '</a>' .
          "</td>");
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo ("</table>");
echo '</BODY>';
echo '</HTML>';

function get_description_from_htmlpage($ahtmlfile)
{
    $tags = get_meta_tags($ahtmlfile);
    $thisdescription = $tags['description'];
    if (isset($thisdescription))
        return $thisdescription;
    else
        return 'No description';
}

function get_title_tag_from_htmlpage($ahtmlfile)
{
    $thisfilecontents = file_get_contents($ahtmlfile);
    if (preg_match('/<title>(.+)<\/title>/', $thisfilecontents, $matches) && isset ($matches[1]))
        return $matches[1];
    else
        return "No Title";
}

?>
```

Comment: How does this work? Does it require a local version of the site, a link to be actively crawled, or just the sitemap.xml file?